# Is it possible to get the distance from the robot to an AR Tag?

Tags: ros, create, ros-groovy, openni-launch, ar-track-alvar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using the ar_track_alvar package to detect ar tags found here: [markers](http://wiki.ros.org/ar_track_alvar?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=markers0to8.png)

I launch the package using this command:

> roslaunch ar_track_alvar ar_track_alvar 4.4 0.08 0.2 /camera/depth_registered/points /camera/rgb/camera_info /base_link

The tag detection works really well and the Kinect is able to detect the tags pretty well. I was wondering however if I could continuously get a distance from the robot to the tag with my callback function with the tag detection. I need some way of getting a distance to the tag. I am using a Create Base and using ROS Groovy.

I appreciate your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214649/is-it-possible-to-get-the-distance-from-the-robot-to-an-ar-tag?/) by [shahvineet98](https://answers.ros.org/users/23078/shahvineet98/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2015-07-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using the markers as @Falko and @Mehdi. said is not the correct way to do this. Markers are intended for visualization only. ar_track_alvar broadcasts a tf frame for each ar tag. You can find the distance by using tf to lookup the transform from whatever robot frame you're interested in (e.g. base_link) to the tag's frame.

See:

- ar_track_alvar [provided tf
  transforms](http://wiki.ros.org/ar_track_alvar#ar_track_alvar.2BAC8-post-fuerte-1.Provided_tf_Transforms)
- tf
  ([C++](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20%28C%2B%2B%29),
  [Python](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20%28Python%29))

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2015-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1